# How to non-parallel testing by Mocha framework?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha just like this:

```
.
.
.
const { describe } = require("mocha");
.
.
.
describe("Desciption1",function(){
   describe("Description2",function(){
      it("Description2'".function(){
               ...
      });
   });
.
.
.
   describe("Description10",function(){
      it("Description10'".function(){
               ...
      });
   });
});
```

As I experienced, Mocha takes tests in parallel. I mean it executes all of `it()`s at the same time. How can I execute them one after another? I need to execute a `it()` so that it started after the previous `it()` done!